# PHP Coding Standards, Widgets and Sanitization

Tags: widgets, escaping, coding-standards

I have an issue with custom widgets and WordPress Coding Standards. When you create a custom widget, your class should have a "widget" method that will display the widget. Something like:

```
<?php
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    ?> <span><?php echo esc_html( 'Great widget', 'text-domain' ); ?></span> <?php
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}
?>
```

While this is perfectly functional, this will not pass PHP code sniffer tests with WordPress coding standards because `$args['after_widget'];` and `$args['before_widget'];` are not escaped...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: More than five years later, the issue persists...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These arguments contain arbitrary HTML and cannot be properly escaped. This is essentially a limitation on how Widgets code was designed and you can see in core Widget classes that no escaping is done on these.

Lessons to learn:

- WP core doesn't consistently adhere to its own coding standards (and getting there isn't considered worth targeted effort);
- passing around chunks of HTML is  bad idea, in your own code pass *data* and render appropriately with proper escaping.

Comment: Ok thanks, glad I'm not crazy. I saw the core widget but figured that may still be a "better" way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem with overly strict coding standards, not with how you should write wordpress code. In this context both parameters are assumed to be valid HTML (they are defined in sidebar registration time).

Anyway in most tools like that there is a way to instruct the linter/sniffer to ignore that line or function.

BTW the standards you are talking about are probably the wordpress.com VIP standards, not the wordpress one - https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/

Comment: Hi Mark, No it's core: https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/develop/WordPress/Sniffs/XSS/EscapeOutputSniff.php

Comment: And yes there are ways to ignore the line...but I just wanted to make sure that that was the way to go here.

Comment: No they are not. The link to the coding standard is the one I have given, the link that you have given is an implementation of that coding standard into the sniffer. The result might be (and probably is) something that is more than the minimal requirements set by wordpress core development. Unlike what @rarst said, core mostly follows its coding standard, mostly because it is very easy to follow ;)

Comment: .... loking more carfully into that github project, and you can see there are several different validatiors maintained there, one of them is the core standard, and the other (the more strick) is the wordpress.com standard

Comment: To be clear escape sniff is part of WordPress Extra ruleset, which is considered addition to baseline WordPress Core ruleset. Of course I would consider escaping to be inherently mandatory, regardless of its _formal_ status in WP coding standards. This is more about it being outside of "coding style" scope than being inessential.

Comment: @Rarst, as long as translations are not supposed to escape the translated string, I don't see how you can escape everywhere in anything wordpress related, and there are several other areas that should not escape, and you will break functionality if you do, like widget titles. For example today I am actually contemplating how to let a user specify &hellip; as a separator in a text input. No way to do it if I just blindly escape everything.

Comment: There are two versions of translation functions — escaping and non–escaping, which should be used appropriately. But this is really tangent to the question, you know where I hang out to chat. :)